# How to get the file content in the OnDrageEnter event from IDragData?

Tags: cefsharp

In an winforms implementation of CefSharp I have implemented the IDragHandler.

In the OnDragEnter event I would like to get the file content.

Currently I am using

```
Dim st As IO.Stream = Nothing
Dim i As Integer = dragData.GetFileContents(st)
```

There is no data written to the stream.

Can you get the file content from a file being dragged from outside (eg desktop) onto the browser?

I assume this is an upstream issue, however, if I drag a selected Outlook item the dragData has no files, or filename but the IsFragment is true and the FragmentText includes what looks like some general info about the email like subject. This is an upstream issue right?

Comment: The `upstream API` says that it gets the file contents when dragged **out** of the webview, see https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefDragData.html#GetFileContents(CefRefPtr%3CCefStreamWriter%3E)

Comment: Makes sense because the filename otherwise shows the full path.

Comment: For anyone who lands here from Google. It looks like the Outlook item issue is getting fixed at Chromium Level https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322605&desc=3. I hope downstream passes on the data in the dragevent as there may not be a file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment to the answer please see [Issue 322605: Drag and Drop support for E-Mails from Microsoft Outlook](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322605&desc=3).

To be complete I wanted to add how I solved this until Chromium catches up.  I am hosting my CEFSharp winforms instance in a WPF window. When the CefSharp OnDragEnter event fires I open an almost transparent popup directly under the mouse pointer. This popup has the drag events for WPF enabled and once they fire and give me the dragged contents i close the popup. It is a little but tricky as the OnDragEnter event from CefSharp fires once the popup is gone but otherwise I can find out what is being dragged.

Comment: How does the WPF frame rate compare when hosting CefSharp via winforms? When adding CefSharp to WPF the frame rate is slow so animations stutter. I may do this as well, to provide this functionality. Do you have a  reference to some example code?

Comment: WPF is slow and I’m not an expert enough to understand why. I think there might be something coming which might make it faster but chromium is simply a windows thing and wpf is always going to be slower.